# Modifying a Column of Excel related to phones

Tags: excel

I have a column of phone numbers
e.g

```
344-444022-22
234325343
(545)3454-3454
```

These are some formats
I want to convert all the phone numbers to simple 345354 format no dashes or brackets and also i ant to add USA Code "1" in front of all numbers

How can i do that in excel?

Comment: Do you want to use VBA or and Excel formula?

Comment: @SoulDZIN excel would be cool . Head i am not an excel user and that;s why i am asking, what to try :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A1 is the reference where the phone number is you could use the following formula in a cell to remove the characters '(' '-' and ')'

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),")",""),"-","")
```

Copying this formula for all of the phone numbers should work if these are the only characters that are used in the different formats.

**EDIT**

If there is another character that you would like to remove, lets assume ' ', you can simply surround this formula with another SUBSTITUTE function, which works like the following:

```
SUBSTITUTE(source_text,text_to_replace,replace_with_this)
```

Making the formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),")",""),"-","")," ","")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a formula:

```
=1&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""),")",""),"(","")
```

There is probably a more concise way to do this. But his should work.